# Como utilizar templateUrl de directive com controller externo?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou desacoplando alguns componentes e estou com dúvida na hora de criar um controller vinculado com o template.

Tenho por exemplo a tela de Login, na minha directive faço:

```
app.directive('appLogin',function(){
  return{
    scope: {},
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'view/usuario/login.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.login);
    }],
  };
});
```

Desta forma consigo pegar todos os valores da tela login e realizar alguma ação, gostaria de realizar uma separação para deixar assim:

```
app.directive('appLogin',function(){
  return{
    scope: {},
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'view/usuario/login.html',
    controller: 'controller/usuario/login.js'
  };
});
```

Desta forma eu iria incluir apenas um arquivo de init.js no index.html e ele iria carregar todos os modulos e controllers que eu preciso.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? esta é a forma correta de realizar modularização em angular? estou separando 1 arquivo para Controller e um para View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar da solução da Thavia poder funcionar, vai depender do seu uso. Eu particularmente não gosto de usar `controller` explicitamente definido no `directive`, ou se quer `controller` com `directive`, pois perde um pouco do propósito dela, criar comportamento independente de outras áreas, mas, cada caso é um caso.

Mas no seu código o problema é a definição do `controller`. Você está referenciando o arquivo físico `JS` e não o `controller` propriamente dito.

```
app.directive('appLogin',function(){
  return{
    scope: {},
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'view/usuario/login.html',
    controller: 'NomeController',
    controllerAs: 'vm' //!Important! Utilize este apenas se você utilizar controllerAs syntax no seu projeto, se não utilize apenas a opção de cima
  };
});
```

Veja a definição de `controller`, você deve referenciar o nome do seu `controller`. Apenas certifique-se de que ele está dentro do mesmo módulo, ou de um módulo já carregado para que possa utilizá-lo.

Comment: Estou desta forma, apenas acrescentando o nome do controller, mas seria legal ele poder incluir o controllador por arquivo sob demanda

Comment: O problema disso é que, por exemplo, ao utilizar um arquivo .min existiriam muitos outros controllers. O que você pode fazer é incluir o módulo através do require ou outro serviço. Eu particularmente utilizo o $ocLazyLoad que funciona muito bem com o ui-router, assim posso carregar módulos ao longo da navegação e utilizar conforme necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode injetar controllers em sua diretiva e então usar angular.extend para trazer pra sua diretiva o $scope, por exemplo:

```
app.controller('ctrlB', function($scope) {

  $scope.bar = 'foo';

});


app.directive('appLogin', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl:'view/usuario/login.html',
    controller: ['$scope','$controller', function($scope, $controller)     {


      angular.extend(this, $controller('ctrlB', { $scope: $scope }));
      console.log($scope.bar); // foo



    }]
  };
});
```